# Extracting CDATA from XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not a programmer, but need some help to find a way of displaying XML content in CDATA using XSL.  For example, the following line:

```
<property id="instruction1" media="screen"><![CDATA[<p>Select the <span class="bold">option</span> you think is correct.</p>]]></property>
```

I need to ONLY display the text between the `<p></p>` tags, i.e. `Select the <span class="bold">option</span> you think is correct.`

If there is a way to exclude the bold formatting tag too so it displays as "*Select the option you think is correct.*" it would super great!

I can post more/all of the XML code if required.

Thanks a lot
Niall

Comment: have you search a little before posting a question?

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use or can you use?

Comment: To macfij: I have been searching for a solution for the last few days. I've found similar problems but no solution that works for my specific problem.

Comment: To Martin: Sorry, I maybe should have specified that I would like to try and write an XLS to display the XML contents in a browser window. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With pure XSLT 3.0 (requires commercial edition of Saxon 9.5) you can simply do

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="property[@media = 'screen']">
  <xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which parses the content of the `property` element with `parse-xml-fragment` and then simply outputs the string value (which is a way of stripping all elements like the `p` and the `span` element).

Comment: Thanks for that Martin. See previous comment though, that I would like to try and write an XLS to display the XML contents in a browser window. Will this work for that?

Comment: Well Saxon 9.5 is an XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 processor that does not work inside of a browser, you would run it outside of a browser to create a HTML result document that could then be loaded and displayed in  browser window, if needed or wanted.